# Show/Hide Components From Other Components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I have a custom hook written to show or hide a list when a button clicked. Below is the custom hook snippet I have written:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function useVisibilityStatus() {

    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect( () => {

        setIsVisible(!isVisible);              


    }, [isVisible]);

    return isVisible;
}

export default useVisibilityStatus;
```

And in another component I have written the logic to view or hide the list.

```
import ProductListView from "../common/ProductListView";
import SideNavView from "../common/SideNavView";
import SimpleMap from '../googlemap/SimpleMap';
import useVisibilityStatus from '../customhooks/useVisibilityStatus';

function ServiceContentView() {
    const listVisible = useVisibilityStatus();

    return (
        <div className="row p-0 vw-100 service-view-body bg-primary position-relative">
            <div className="zindex-value position-absolute">
              <div className="service-view-sidenav float-end">
                <SideNavView />
              </div>
            </div>
            {listVisible && <ProductListView />}
            <SimpleMap />
        </div>
    );
}

export default ServiceContentView;
```

And in the `SideNavView` I have the button where upon clicking it shows the product list or hides it if it is visible. The `SideNavView` is incomplete, as I am bit struggling on how to fit my requirement in ReactJS.

```
import useVisibilityStatus from '../customhooks/useVisibilityStatus';

function SideNavView() {
    const   listVisible = useVisibilityStatus();

    const handleClick = () => {
        
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="row">                
                <div className="card p-0 w-100 border-radius-none sidenav-view" onClick={handleClick}>
                    <span className="text-center mt-2 text-white">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-card-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M14.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z"/>
                            <path d="M5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 5 8zm0-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1-5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zM4 8a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm0 2.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                    <div className="card-body p-0">
                        <h5 className="card-title text-center text-white">View Products</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SideNavView;
```

Comment: Your `useVisibilityStatus` hook will cause infinite render.

Comment: @kennarddh: yes, at the moment it is infinitely rendering. The functionality is still incomplete. I want to show/hide my product list upon a button click in another component. Namely in the SideNavView component

Comment: To clarify @kennarddh comment, the `useVisibilityStatus` implements a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `isVisible` and unconditionally updates that state with `setIsVisible(!isVisible);`. It will render loop.

Comment: @DrewReese: yes it is, please see my above comment

Comment: So you want to show `ProductListView` when button in `SideNavView` is clicked?

Comment: @kennarddh: yes, that's what I am after.

Comment: Can you clarify what the use case is and what exactly the problem is or where you are stuck? It sounds like you want a "single" `isVisible` state that can be toggled from around the app. Is this accurate?

Comment: @DrewReese: Basically what I want is, I have a button in "SideNavView" where upon clicking the button on that component, a list "ProductListView", in "ServiceComponentView" shows if it is hidden or hides if it is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React hooks don't magically share state, so with the current `useVisibilityStatus` implementation they will each have and update their own state independently.

What you can do is create a React Context to hold the single `isVisible` state value and expose it and an updater function to consumers.

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const VisibleContext = createContext({
  isVisible: false,
  toggleIsVisible: () => {},
});

export const useVisibilityStatus = () => useContext(VisibleContext);

const VisibleContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const toggleIsVisible = () => setIsVisible(isVisible => !isVisible);

  return (
    <VisibleContext.Provider value={{ isVisible, toggleIsVisible }}>
      {children}
    </VisibleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default VisibleContextProvider;
```

The `VisibleContextProvider` just needs to wrap the part of the ReactTree that contains the components that need to access its context value, e.g. `ServiceContentView` and `SideNavView`, and these components use the `useVisibilityStatus` to read the current `isVisible` state value or access the `toggleIsVisible` updater function.

```
import VisibleContextProvider from '../path/to/VisibleContextProvider';

...

return (
  ...
  <VisibleContextProvider>

    ...
    <ServiceContentView />
    ...

  </VisibleContextProvider>
  ...
);
```

```
import ProductListView from "../common/ProductListView";
import SideNavView from "../common/SideNavView";
import SimpleMap from '../googlemap/SimpleMap';
import { useVisibilityStatus } from '../path/to/VisibleContextProvider';

function ServiceContentView() {
  const { isVisible } = useVisibilityStatus();

  return (
    <div className="row p-0 vw-100 service-view-body bg-primary position-relative">           
      <div className="zindex-value position-absolute">
        <div className="service-view-sidenav float-end">
          <SideNavView />
        </div>
      </div>
      {isVisible && <ProductListView />}
      <SimpleMap />          
    </div>
  );
}

export default ServiceContentView;
```

```
import { useVisibilityStatus } from '../path/to/VisibleContextProvider';

function SideNavView() {
  const { toggleIsVisible } = useVisibilityStatus();

  const handleClick = () => {
    toggleIsVisible();
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="row">                
        <div
          className="...."
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <span className="text-center mt-2 text-white">
            ...
            </svg>
          </span>
          <div className="card-body p-0">
            <h5 className="....">View Products</h5>
          </div>
        </div>                
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SideNavView;
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!
What's the best practice for dealing with Context components? It seems odd to have VisibleContextProvider.jsx just sitting in the /components directory, since it's more of a set of functional rules than an actual component (it doesn't really represent an HTML module, right?)
Would it be more of best practice to set that as a parent container (that returns a container div or something, for example) to the other two components, or does that not really matter?

Comment: @PatrickLines-Mattei If you are specifically referring to the fact that `VisibleContextProvider` basically only renders its `children` prop and doesn't contribute any additional UI of its own, and whether or not this component should be organized into a `/components` directory or some other directory.... well, how you decide to organize your project files is subjective and really up to and what works well/best for your and/or the team. I hope I didn't misunderstand your question though.

Comment: Nope, that's what I was referring to. Like you said, I'm used to individual component files usually referring to some kind of module in the UI. But maybe I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom hooks for that task. The better solution is to save visibility status into Main component's container and pass it as props to child components.

Answer (score 0):

To share state between deeply nested component you can use `context`

`VisibilityContext.jsx`

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react'

const VisibilityContext = createContext({
  Visibility: {}
})

export const VisibilityContextProvider = ({ children })=>{
  const [Visibility, SetVisibility] = useState({})

  return (
    <VisibilityContext.Provider value={{ Visibility, SetVisibility }}>
      {children}
    </VisibilityContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default VisibilityContext
```

`useVisibilityStatus.js`

```js
import { useState, useContext, useCallback } from "react";

import VisibilityContext from 'path/to/VisibilityContext.jsx'

const useVisibilityStatus = (scope) => {
  const { Visibility, SetVisibility } = useContext(VisibilityContext)
  
  const ToggleVisibility = useCallback(() => {
    SetVisibility(prev => !prev)
  }, [SetVisibility])

  return {
    IsVisible: Visibility[scope] ?? false,
    ToggleVisibility
  }
}

export default useVisibilityStatus;
```

You need to wrap the `SideNavView` and `ServiceContentView` with `VisibilityContextProvider`

`SideNavView` and `ServiceContentView` Parent

```
import { VisibilityContextProvider } from 'path/to/VisibilityContext.jsx'

const ... = () => {
  return (
    <VisibilityContextProvider>
       {/* SideNavView and ServiceContentView */}
    </VisibilityContextProvider>
  )
}
```

`ServiceContentView.jsx`

```js
import useVisibilityStatus from 'path/to/useVisibilityStatus.js'

const ServiceContentView = () => {
  const { IsVisible } = useVisibilityStatus('ServiceContentView')

  return (
    ...
    {IsVisible && <ProductListView />}
    ...
  )
}
```

`SideNavView.jsx`

```js
import useVisibilityStatus from 'path/to/useVisibilityStatus.js'

const SideNavView = () => {
  const { ToggleVisibility } = useVisibilityStatus('ServiceContentView')

  const handleClick = () => {
    ToggleVisibility()
  }
}
```